# Problem with JW Player Embed Code - Flash with HTML5 Fallback

Tags: flash, html, video, html5-video, jwplayer

I'm trying to setup my page to play a video with the following specs:

- Use licensed JW player
- Flash player to be used, HTML5 fall back
- I'd also like to provide alternative file formats for the HTML5 fallback (ogg, webm)
- Use the RTMP streaming method to deliver the videos via cloudfront

Here is a link to my test page:
http://coachesmarketingcenter.com/test_new_ppts/index3.html

Here is the embed code I'm currently using:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>

    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>Test New Videos</title>

    <script type='text/javascript' src='http://coachesmarketingcenter.com/test_new_ppts/swfobject.js'></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://coachesmarketingcenter.com/test_new_ppts/jwplayer.js"></script> 

</head>
<body>

    <div id="container1"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        jwplayer("container1").setup({
            file: "TestNewVideos/MyNewVideo.mp4",
            provider: "rtmp",
            streamer: "rtmp://s2cr83yb7q2jav.cloudfront.net/cfx/st",
            width: 640,
            height: 480,
            modes: [{
                type: "flash",
                src: "http://coachesmarketingcenter.com/test_new_ppts/player.swf"
            },{
                type: "html5",
                config: {
                    file: "http://dn9lu4lqda9r4.cloudfront.net/TestNewVideos/MyNewVideo.mp4",
                    provider: "video"
                }
            levels: [
                { file: "http://dn9lu4lqda9r4.cloudfront.net/TestNewVideos/MyNewVideo.mp4" },    // H.264 version
                { file: "http://dn9lu4lqda9r4.cloudfront.net/TestNewVideos/MyNewVideo.ogg" },    // Ogg Theora version
            ]
        });
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Not sure what question is - seems to work ok for me?

Comment: It looks like your video file is invalid. Try using a different link.

Answer (score 0):

code I'm currently using:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<html lang="en">
<header>
<title>PramCrazyPlayer</title>
<link href="https://pramcrazyplayer.000webhostapp.com/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<meta property="og:type" content="video">
<meta property="og:video:type" content="video/mp4">
<meta name="robots" content="noindex" />
<META NAME="GOOGLEBOT" CONTENT="NOINDEX" />
<meta property="og:title" content="ไม่พบชื่อที่แน่ชัดของวีดีโอ">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />
<div id="myVideo"><img src="https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-C5k7c4cF2S4/XAzihgl3s3I/AAAAAAAABdE/9yclPt2hKaU_sgimTCeOW12W4uuZBrTAQCLcBGAs/s1600/error.gif" width="100%"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jwplayer.com/libraries/jwplayer.js"></script>
  <style type="text/css">

  .jw-svg-icon-play path {
      display: none;
  }
  .jw-svg-icon-play {
      background-image: url('https://visualpharm.com/assets/54/Play-595b40b65ba036ed117d4529.svg');
      background-size: contain;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
  }

  .jw-svg-icon-buffer path {
      display: none;
  }

  .jw-svg-icon-buffer {
      background-image: url('http://www.henghengled.com/img/layout/spinner.gif');
      background-size: contain;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
  }

  .jw-svg-icon-replay path {
      display: none;
  }

  .jw-svg-icon-replay {
      background-image: url('https://visualpharm.com/assets/922/Repeat-595b40b65ba036ed117d4560.svg');
      background-size: contain;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
  }

  .jw-svg-icon-pause path {
      display: none;
  }

  .jw-svg-icon-pause {
      background-image: url('https://visualpharm.com/assets/327/Pause-595b40b65ba036ed117d4512.svg');
      background-size: contain;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
  }

  .jw-svg-icon-rewind path {
      display: none;
  }

  .jw-svg-icon-rewind {
      background-image: url('https://visualpharm.com/assets/151/Rewind-595b40b65ba036ed117d456b.svg');
      background-size: contain;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
  }

  .jw-svg-icon-stop path {
      display: none;
  }

  .jw-svg-icon-stop {
      background-image: url('https://visualpharm.com/assets/891/Stop-595b40b65ba036ed117d45cc.svg');
      background-size: contain;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
  }

</style>
</header>
<body>
<div class="container">
<script type="text/javascript">
    var playerInstance = jwplayer("myVideo");
        playerInstance.setup({
        sources: [{"label":"1080p","type":"video/mp4","file":"myvideo.mp4"},
                  {"label":"720p","type":"video/mp4","file":"myvideo.mp4"},
                  {"label":"480p","type":"video/mp4","file":"myvideo.mp4"},
                  {"label":"360p","type":"video/mp4","file":"myvideo.mp4"},
                  {"label":"270p","type":"video/mp4","file":"myvideo.mp4"},
                  {"label":"144p","type":"video/mp4","file":"myvideo.mp4"},
                  ]
,
        controls: true,
        title: "ไม่พบชื่อที่แน่ชัดของวีดีโอ",
        image: 'https://pramcrazyplayer.000webhostapp.com/bg-04.jpg',
        width: "100%",
        height: "100%",
        aspectratio: "16:9",
        fullscreen: "true",
        primary: 'html5',
        hlshtml: false,
        autostart: false,
        mute: false,

        });
    </script>
<!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-64601221-1"></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());

  gtag('config', 'UA-64601221-1');
</script>
</html>
</html>
```